# Arithmetic of continued fractions, does it exist?

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions

I'm interested in the arithmmetic of continued fractions and specially in multiplication. Consider 
$$
f(x)=\cfrac{f_{0}(x)}{1-\cfrac{f_{1}(x)}{1+f_{1}(x)-\cfrac{f_{2}(x)}{1+f_{2}(x)-\cfrac{f_{3}(x)}{1+f_{3}(x)-\cdots}}}}
$$

and

$$
g(x)=\cfrac{g_{0}(x)}{1-\cfrac{g_{1}(x)}{1+g_{1}(x)-\cfrac{g_{2}(x)}{1+g_{2}(x)-\cfrac{g_{3}(x)}{1+g_{3}(x)-\cdots}}}}
$$

Are there arithmetic rules (algorithms) for the multiplication of continued fractions? Specifically, is it possible to obtain a continued fraction $h(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$ where

$$
h(x)=\cfrac{h_{0}(x)}{1-\cfrac{h_{1}(x)}{1+h_{1}(x)-\cfrac{h_{2}(x)}{1+h_{2}(x)-\cfrac{h_{3}(x)}{1+h_{3}(x)-\cdots}}}}
$$

I've found [this](http://hack.org/mc/writings/hackerdom/hakmem/cf.html), but I'd like more. Does anyone here knows of papers, algorithms, etc?

Thanks.

---

**Update 1:**
Another [link](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/57/92/PDF/RR-0760.pdf).

Comment: Well, there's always [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use a format that differs from the ordinary continued fraction? What do you win by doing so?

Comment: How would you represent the above in the "ordinary continued fraction" format?

Answer (score 7):

[Bill Gosper](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/cf.html) has invented an algorithm for performing analytic addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division using continued fractions. It requires keeping track of eight integers which are conceptually arranged at the polyhedron vertices of a cube. Although this algorithm has not appeared in print, similar algorithms have been constructed by Vuillemin (1987) and Liardet and Stambul (1998)

For illustration how to perform some continued fraction arithmetic see [this](http://pauljmccarthy.us/Cfrac/CF_Arithmetic.htm).

Comment: [Also here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html)

Comment: To expand on J.M.'s comment: This is a verbatim copy of the wolfram alpha page @J.M. is linking to. See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76411/how-to-construct-magic-squares-of-even-order/76429#76429) where the same thing happened, a bit more shamelessly.

Comment: Plagiarism alert indeed! The text above was copied straight from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularContinuedFraction.html