# What is the algorithm for performing continued fraction arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, continued-fractions

I am trying to write a python package for doing exact arithmetic with continued fractions, I've been looking for a good while now but can't find any good reference anywhere.
I've already read gosper's 1972 Hakmem notes and checked these places; [rosetta](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Continued_fraction/Arithmetic), [plover](https://perl.plover.com/classes/cftalk/), and several others.

None of them explicitly explain how to decide whether to ingest from x or y when doing an arithmetic operation on continued fractions x and y.
I started with the plover slides which has absolutely ruined all other sources for me because the slides have everything reversed, these slides do provide a condition to use and sample code but they don't match and neither seems to work.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76036/arithmetic-of-continued-fractions-does-it-exist

Comment: Plover slides are not bad. While it touches the operations among x and y at the end, it doesn't give it to us with a silver spoon. [Here](https://srossd.com/posts/2020-09-18-gosper-1/) is another attempt to explain Gosper Algorithm which made me understand better in the sense that it actually turns out to be no different than finding the CF coefficients of a simple rational. Other than a few typos it is really good. Just give it a try.

Comment: @Redu Thanks for the link, but it appears to be broken. I was too slow checking my inbox I guess :(

Comment: Ryski:  The link is working for me now (the one in @Redu's Comment).

Answer (score 3):

So it is very easy. To perform an arithmetic operation among two Simple Continued Fractions (SCF) we have to express the result or the current state which will eventually become the result, as a function $z(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are the operand SCFs and let $z$ be the resulting SCF.

$z(x,y)=\frac{axy+bx+cy+d}{exy+fx+gy+h}$ where;

$x=[p_0,p_1,p_2,...,p_i]$ at hand

$y=[q_0,q_1,q_2,...,q_j]$ at hand

$z=[r_0,r_1,r_2,...,r_k]$ to be constructed

Right now I suggest you to read the remaining part first and then go over it backwards once more.

Before we start ingesting coefficients from $x$ or $y$ i have to explain how to choose whether to ingest from $x$ or $y$. Apparently it just doesn't matter as long as you deplete all $x$ and $y$ coefficients. I will actually do some tests on different strategies but for the time being we may use [Ross Dempsey's suggestion](https://srossd.com/posts/2020-09-18-gosper-1/).

If $|\frac{b}{f}-\frac{d}{h}|>|\frac{c}{g}-\frac{d}{h}|$ then choose $x$;

**Edit:** I have done some tests and it really doesn't matter. My choice is to avoid a comparison and interlace from $x$ and $y$ up until one of them finishes and then continue with the operand which has remaining coefficients.

Let's assume that we start ingesting from $x$. Remember that $x=p_0+\frac{1}{x_1}$. Which means we assign $(p_0+\frac{1}{x_1})$ for $x$ in the $z(x,y)=\frac{axy+bx+cy+d}{exy+fx+gy+h}$ formula to get the next state like;

$z(x,y)=\frac{a(p_0+\frac{1}{x_1})y+b(p_0+\frac{1}{x_1})+cy+d}{e(p_0+\frac{1}{x_1})y+f(p_0+\frac{1}{x_1})+gy+h}\implies\frac{(ap+c)xy+(bp+d)x+ay+b}{(ep+g)xy+(fp+h)x+ey+f}$

Which means an ingession from $x$ always yields a transformation like;

$\left\langle\begin{matrix}a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\end{matrix}\right\rangle\implies\left\langle\begin{matrix}ap+c&bp+d&a&b\\ep+g&fp+h&e&f\end{matrix}\right\rangle$

Now let's assume that we ingest from $y$. Remember that $y=q_0+\frac{1}{y_1}$. Which means we assign $(q_0+\frac{1}{y_1})$ for $y$ in the $z(x,y)=\frac{axy+bx+cy+d}{exy+fx+gy+h}$ formula to get the next state like;

$z(x,y)=\frac{ax(q_0+\frac{1}{y_1})+bx+c(q_0+\frac{1}{y_1})+d}{ex(q_0+\frac{1}{y_1})+fx+g(q_0+\frac{1}{y_1})+h}\implies\frac{(aq+b)xy+ax+(cq+d)y+c}{(eq+f)xy+ex+(gq+h)y+g}$

Which means an ingession from $y$ always yields a transformation like;

$\left\langle\begin{matrix}a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\end{matrix}\right\rangle\implies\left\langle\begin{matrix}aq+b&a&cq+d&c\\eq+f&e&gq+h&g\end{matrix}\right\rangle$

We keep ingesting from $x$ and $y$ up until $\lfloor\frac{a}{e}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{b}{f}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{c}{g}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{d}{h}\rfloor$. When this condition is satisfied it means we have discovered a coefficient of $z$ such as $r_0=\lfloor\frac{a}{e}\rfloor$. Accordingly we subtract $r_0$ from $z$ and reciprocate the result.

Remember that $z=r_0+\frac{1}{z_1}$ and we have just discovered $r_0$ which means we have to subtract $r_0$ from $z$ and calculate the egession transformation for $z_1$.

$z=r_0+\frac{1}{z_1}=\frac{axy+bx+cy+d}{exy+fx+gy+h}\implies z-r_0=\frac{1}{z_1}\implies z_1=(z-r_0)^{-1}\implies\frac{exy+fx+gy+h}{(a\bmod{e})xy+(b\bmod{f})x+(c\bmod{g})y+(d\bmod{h})}$

Remember that $r_0=\lfloor\frac{a}{e}\rfloor$ is an integer and we are interested in the remainder of the division to reciprocate. This actually means $a\bmod{e}$. The transformation of egession is;

$\left\langle\begin{matrix}a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\end{matrix}\right\rangle\implies\left\langle\begin{matrix}e&f&g&h\\a\bmod{e}&b\bmod{f}&c\bmod{g}&d\bmod{h}\end{matrix}\right\rangle$

After egession we may still need further egessions if the above egession requirements satisfy. Once we reach to a state at which no more egession is possible then continue with ingession from $x$ and $y$ exactly as we have done before, up until we need another egession. After some time both of the $x$ and $y$ coefficients will deplete ($x_n=p_n+\frac{1}{\infty}$) and we will eventually end up with no $x$ and $y$ terms to carry on but a simple fraction. At this moment we already have obtained some $z$ coefficients like $[r_0,r_1,..]$ and a fraction. We simply convert the fraction into SCF and concatenate it's coefficients to the previously obtained $z$ coefficients to finalize the result.

So how do we add two SCFs like $x+y$? This addition is in fact turns our $z(x,y)$ function into $z(x,y) = \frac{x+y}{1}$.

Going back to the original $z(x,y)$ function; $z(x,y) = \frac{axy+bx+cy+d}{exy+fx+gy+h}$ we can now insert $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ values to start with the addition like

$\frac{0xy+1x+1y+0}{0xy+0x+0y+1}\implies\left\langle\begin{matrix}0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{matrix}\right\rangle$

This is in fact a powerful tool which can combine multiple simple arithmetic operations into one operation, all at once. Consider this $\frac{(x + 3)(y + 4)}{(x - y)} = \frac{1xy+4x+3y+12}{0xy+1x-1y+0}$. All you need to do is to start with

$\left\langle\begin{matrix}1&4&3&12\\0&1&-1&0\end{matrix}\right\rangle$

The above matrix like thingy is in fact nothing but a binary operator like $+$ or $\times$ for SFCs. However it can be morphed to take the shape of the required composition of individual arithmetic operators. I would rather call it a **"Composable Binary Operator"** for SCFs. Once you embed multiple operations, it just does it's things at the same number of iterations. This is very powerful.

**Note:** Depending on the language of your choice, the egession formula can yield wrong results especially for subtraction or other operations if negative numbers are involved. As i am told while it is still OK for Mathematica language, for the wast majority of languages it's best to replace all modulus operators with remainder logic. In short, Replace $a\bmod{e}$ with $a-r_n.e$ where $r_n$ is $\lfloor\frac{a}{e}\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks for such an in depth answer, I have since spent quite a bit of time on this but never thought about the egestion as being the modulo operator. That's kind of interesting, I look forward to finding some time to come back to this again as it sounds like that solves the case where only one continued fraction operand is infinite. I'm not giving myself the luxury of assuming continued fractions will be finite, I just alternate x and y but I'm limited to the rationals whichever strategy I try. Where both are infinite is trickier and I think will require an extra discrete arithmetic.

Comment: @Ryski Please check the last paragraph where I mention the limitation of the modulo operator. As per CF arithmetic among irrationals and for some more you may read [this series of mine](https://medium.com/p/3e4bba93db5f) which comes in 6 parts as of now and explains more on this topic.