# Algorithm to add continued fractions

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, continued-fractions

Lets say I have two continued fractions:
$$a=[a_0; \overline{a_1, a_2,a_3...}]$$
$$b=[b_0; \overline{b_1, b_2,b_3...}]$$
How do I add them together?

Comment: You could compose conversion to decimal, decimal addition, and conversion back to continued fraction. All of these can be done in a "streaming" fashion so that you only read elements as you need them to produce output.

Comment: See Item [101B in HAKMEM](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/cf.html) for Gosper's algorithms for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division of continued fractions.

Comment: @EricTowers I didn't see that before. Thank you!

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4174186/735404)